# Opencart sold in x days

Tags: php, sql, opencart

I need to add a new column to Opencart admin > Catalog > Products page to display the total quantity sold of each product in the last 30 days next to the 'edit' button on each row.

I can't see this being too difficult, but I'm not sure how I would go about it as I am aware that it would be poor practice to just add a a line of code to do an sql lookup in the products.tpl page.

How would I retrieve this information and what is the best way to implement it?

(Opencart 1.5.6)

Comment: You need to edit product model and controller to get relevant data, then pass it to tpl as everything else.

Comment: I added the following to model\catalog\product.php

    public function totalsold30days(){
    $query = "SELECT sum(op.quantity) AS total FROM order_product op LEFT JOIN `order` o ON (op.order_id = o.order_id) WHERE product_id=123 AND DATE(date_added) >= CURDATE()-INTERVAL 1 MONTH AND order_status_id=3;";
    return $this->db->query($query);
    }

and the following to controller/catalog/product.php

    public function gettotalsold30days() {
    $this -> data ['sold30'] = $this -> model_catalog_product -> totalsold30days();
    }

But can't echo $sold30 in product_list.tpl any suggestions?